# Why do classes that are toll-free bridged with Core Foundation counterparts not call -dealloc upon final release?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I was trying to write some code that would be invoked when any object was deallocated by swizzling the `-[NSObject dealloc]` method. I understand this is a bad idea and won't be pursuing it (so please refrain from pointing this out), but along the way I discovered that classes such as NSDictionary and NSString that are toll-free bridged with Core Foundation counterparts such as CFDictionary and CFString do not call `-dealloc` upon final release.

This code demonstrates this phenomenon:

```
- (void)loggedDealloc {
    NSLog(@"Deallocation of %@", self.class);
    [self loggedDealloc];
}

- (void)testDeallocSwizzleOnTestObject {
    Method deallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([TestObject class], NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"));
    Method loggedDeallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(loggedDealloc));
    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);

    TestObject * testObject = [[TestObject alloc] init];
    testObject = nil; // calls release under ARC

    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);
}

- (void)testDeallocSwizzleOnNSDictionary {
    Method deallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSDictionary class], NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"));
    Method loggedDeallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(loggedDealloc));
    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = nil; // calls release under ARC

    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);
}

- (void)testDeallocSwizzleOnNSString {
    Method deallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([NSString class], NSSelectorFromString(@"dealloc"));
    Method loggedDeallocMethod = class_getInstanceMethod([self class], @selector(loggedDealloc));
    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);

    NSDictionary * dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    dictionary = nil; // calls release under ARC

    method_exchangeImplementations(deallocMethod, loggedDeallocMethod);
}
```

In the above tests, only the swizzling of TestObject will cause the logging of the deallocation to occur. The swizzling of NSDictionary and NSString have no effect.

I suspect this is because the toll-free bridged classes implement `-release` to perform a CFRelease instead of calling `[super release]`, thus the memory is deallocated by Core Foundation and no call to `-dealloc` occurs at all.

Can anyone confirm this is the case and is it documented anywhere? If so, is there any way to inject custom code into the deallocation of these toll-free bridged classes?

Answer (score 3):

(Heh. Been there. Done that. :)

Calls to `dealloc` are only guaranteed for subclasses of the various classes.  There are a number of classes -- mostly the various CF/NS bridged classes -- for which `dealloc` is never called because there is never a need to do so [an internal implementation detail].

To do what you want to do, it is far cleaner to subclass the desired class, encapsulate an instance of the original class as the backing store, and then override the primitive methods (every class cluster class has a very minimal set of primitive methods -- I think `NSString` has all of 2 methods) and then override the memory management methods on that new class.  Because it is a subclass, the "short-circuiting" you see with the existing classes will no longer come into play.